# Most efficient Javascript way to check if an object within an unknown object exists

Tags: javascript, performance

This is something that I come up against quite often in Javascript. Let's say I have an object like this:

```
var acquaintances = {
   types: {
      friends: {
         billy: 6,
         jascinta: 44,
         john: 91
         others: ["Matt", "Phil", "Jenny", "Anna"]
      },
      coworkers: {
         matt: 1
      }
   }
}
```

In my theoretical program, all I know for sure is that `acquaintances` is an object; I have no idea whether `acquaintances.types` has been set, or whether `friends` has been set within it.

**How can I efficiently check whether `acquaintances.types.friends.others` exists?**

What I would normally do is:

```
if(acquaintances.types){
  if(aquaintances.types.friends){
    if(acquaintances.types.friends.others){
       // do stuff with the "others" array here
    } 
  }
}
```

Aside from being laborious, these nested `if` statements are a bit of a nightmare to manage (in practice my objects have far more levels than this!). But if I were to just try something like `if(acquaintances.types.friends.others){)` straight off the bat, and `types` hasn't been set yet, then the program will crash.

What ways does Javascript have of doing this in a neat, manageable way?

Comment: CoffeeScript has a `?` operator which fits your description, see [here](https://arcturo.github.io/library/coffeescript/02_syntax.html). Not aware of a simple trick in plain JS.

Comment: BTW it is not more *efficient* in terms of execution time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative approach is:

```
((acquaintances.types || {}).friends || {}).others
```

which is shorter than other solutions, but may or may not thrill you.

You can also build a little helper to make the same idea a tiny bit more palatable:

```
function maybe(o) { return o || {}; }
```

Now you can do

```
maybe(maybe(acquaintances.types).friends).others
```

If you don't mind writing property names as strings, you could make a little helper:

```
function maybe(obj) {
  return Object.defineProperty(
    obj || {}, 
    'get', 
    { value: function(prop) { return maybe(obj[prop]); }
  );
}
```

Now you can write

```
maybe(acquaintances.types').get('friends').others
```

In ES6, you can do this, albeit clumsily, using destructuring assignment with defaults:

```
var { types: { friends: { others } = {} } = {} } = acquaintances;
```

If you want to use this in an expression context, instead of assigning to a variable, in theory you could use argument destructuring:

```
(({ types: { friends: { others } = {} } = {} }) => others)(acquaintances)
```

After all is said and done, the standard approach remains

```
acquaintances.types && 
  acquaintances.types.friends && 
  acquaintances.types.friends.others
```

This is why there is an active (?) [discussion](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/existential-operator-null-propagation-operator) in the ES6 design groups about a CoffeeScript-like existential operator, but it does not seem to be converging very rapidly.

Answer (score 3):

It's not nice in JavaScript.

You could add them to one big condition...

```
if (obj.prop && obj.prop.someOtherProp) { }
```

...or write a helper function where you pass an object and a string...

```
var isPropSet = function(object, propPath) {
    return !! propPath.split('.')
           .reduce(function(object, prop) { return object[prop] || {}; }, object);
};

isPropSet(obj, 'prop.someOtherProp);
```

...or you could use CoffeeScript and its `?` operator...

```
obj.prop?.someOtherProp
```

You could also wrap the lookup in a `try/catch`, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I think you need to `return object[prop] || {};`; otherwise a call such as `isPropSet(obj, 'prop.foo.bar')` will generate a run-time error.

Comment: @torazaburo Yes, you're right, it shouldn't blow up while testing for properties.

Answer (score 3):

The and operator is sequential so you can do this without nesting if statements.

```
if(acquaintances.types && aquaintances.types.friends && acquaintances.types.friends.others){
    //acquaintances.types.friends.others exists!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this:

```
if(acquaintances.types){
  if(aquaintances.types.friends){
    if(acquaintances.types.friends.others){
       // do stuff with the "others" array here
    } 
  }
}
```

Try this:

```
   if(acquaintances &&
      acquaintances.types &&
      acquaintances.types.friends &&
      acquaintances.types.friends.others) {
    }
```

Or

```
acquaintances &&
acquaintances.types &&
acquaintances.types.friends &&
acquaintances.types.friends.others ?
doSomething() : doSomethingElse()
```